# Bridge a call from sip phone to real phone using freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

How to bridge a call to real phone from a sip phone in Freeswitch. I have used following command but it didn’t work

```
<action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/ytel.com/xxxxxx@ip"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: dialplan which I used is <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/ytel.com/xxxxxx@gatewayip"/>
please let me know if there are any changes to make it work. Your help makes a lot for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the gateway ytel.com set up, then you shouldn't have @ip, it should be:

`<action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/ytel.com/xxxxxx"/>`

You either use `sofia/gateway/$myCarrier/$number` OR `sofia/$profile/$number@$IPorDomain`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried with <action application="bridge" data="sofia/gateway/ytel.com/xxxxxx"/> but it didn't call the real phone. you also said that use $mycarried,$profile, can I know what are they?

Comment: What happened? Can you save the log to http://pastebin.freeswitch.org/ (read the message).

Comment: $mycarrier is the gateway's parameter - which gateway ID.
The $profile would be for just using sofia/external or whatever you called the profile, for bridging directly to an IP.